# java error: cannot find symbol stack.size()

Tags: java, count, stack, size

I'm getting confused. I checked the parameters of the size() method in java, and I know that it is part of the Vector class which the Stack class inherits. Why isn't this method working on my stack? I want to know the size of the stack. Is there any other way to get the size if not this way?

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class InfixCalculator
{
...
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

    while((stack.size() > 0) && (stack.peek() != "(")
}
```

> ```
>              ^ symbol: method size()
>                location: variable stack of type Stack<String>
> ```

```
public class Stack<String> implelments StackInter<String>
{
     public void push()
    {
        ...
    }   
    public String pop()
    {
        ...
    }
    public boolean isEmptyStack()
    {
        ...
    }
    public String peek()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm sorry. I should've mentioned that I can't import the Stack class. **I had to create my own class stack. Is there a way to get the size of the stack without creating a method for it in my Stack class?**

Comment: The error occurs because `stack` is undefined. Do note that this stack and the stack used by Java are different. This method works on user-defined stacks.

Comment: I forgot to include it, but I do have a stack declaration. I added it to the above code. I'm sorry!

Comment: How can `Stack<String>` implement `StackInter<String>`? `Stack<String>` is the class that has already been defined. Moreover, implementing or extending that class does not necessarily give access to all of its methods and `size()` might be one of them. Do tell us why you are unable to import the `Stack` class. Solving that might solve the problem easily.

Comment: My teacher said I can't

Comment: Oh well then I guess your teacher wants you to implement stacks from scratch. Doing that might take a little more time but your concepts would become clearer. And once you have implemented it from scratch, you can easily write your own method to calculate the size. Shouldn't be very difficult from there.

Comment: I have updated my answer with another link. That should get you started. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample code to get the size of your `stack` if this is what you intend to do-

```
Stack<String> sk=new Stack<String>();

sk.push("a");
sk.push("c");
sk.push("e");
sk.push("d");

int sizeOfStack=sk.size();

System.out.println("Size of Stack :"+sizeOfStack);
```

**Output**

```
Size of Stack :4
```

**Source:** http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/java-how-to-get-size-of-stack/

**Further reading:** http://morbidjava.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-impliment-stack-data-structure.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `size` method within your `Stack` class in order to call it.  You could also extend or implement some other `Collections` style class that already has the method.  If you don't have a `size` method in `Stack` and there isn't one in `StackInter` then there is nothing to be called.